# JavaScript encodeURIComponent With Backslash

Tags: javascript, encoding

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) says the following about `encodeURIComponent` function:

> This function encodes special characters. In addition, 
>   it encodes the following characters: `, / ? : @ & = + $ #`.

Does that mean that it cannot encode a backslash (`\`)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the following characters: `, / ? : @ & = + $ # .`

This definition is vague as to what "special characters" are. It sounds like a comparison between `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`. Both will correctly escape `\` as `%5C`, so you don't have to worry about backslashes.

`encodeURI` will leave the listed characters as it is assumed that the entire URI is being encoded:

```
encodeURI('http://example.com/foo bar/baz.html');
//produces "http://example.com/foo%20bar/baz.html"
```

`encodeURIComponent` will escape *everything* as it is assumed that the string is to be used as part of a query-string:

```
'http://example.com?foo=' + encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/fizz/buzz.html');
//produces "http://example.com?foo=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffizz%2Fbuzz.html"
```